# Disable paste and select all function button from textformfield in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I want to disable all the functionality related to copy, paste and select all on the press of `textformfield` in the flutter. I have a password field which can take keyboard hint and able to paste data by default but when I perform the operation like calling login service then password field gone wrong.

```
 TextFormField(
      obscureText: true,
      style: styleText,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
      controller: _passwordController,
      focusNode: _passwordFocus,
      onFieldSubmitted: (term){
        _passwordFocus.unfocus();
      },
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      validator: validatePassword,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          focusedBorder: border,
          border: border,
          enabledBorder: border,
          hintStyle: styleText,
          hintText: 'Password'),
      onSaved: (String val) {
        _password = val;
      },
    ),
```

Comment: Simple way is just disable long click event of your `TextFormField`

Comment: @NileshRathod how can I access `longpress` of the text field.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use the `enableinteractiveSelection : false` to Disable the copy/paste.

```
TextFormField(
          enableInteractiveSelection: false,
          obscureText: true,
          style: styleText,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
          controller: _passwordController,
          focusNode: _passwordFocus,
          onFieldSubmitted: (term){
            _passwordFocus.unfocus();
          },
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          validator: validatePassword,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              focusedBorder: border,
              border: border,
              enabledBorder: border,
              hintStyle: styleText,
              hintText: 'Password'),
          onSaved: (String val) {
            _password = val;
          },
        ),
```

Comment: is there a way to disable copy paste but not the movement of caret?

Comment: for someone who want to disable copy paste but not the movement of caret use Toolbaroptions. And if u get bool is not a subtype of Toolbaroptions upgrade ur flutter version. But take care while upgrading flutter version

Answer (score 15):

You can try this to `disable any particular option` not all the option.

```
 TextFormField(
      toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(
        copy: true,
        cut: true,
        paste: false,
        selectAll: false,
      ),
    ...
    ..
    .
```

Comment: It helps to a certain point. You can still 'paste' via the keyboard native options.

Comment: Any way to disable pasting completely ( you can paste from the keyboard menu) ?

Comment: Hi, @RichaShah you can check the other answer because I am not working on flutter nowadays.