# How to disable copy/paste in Textfield Flutter Web

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a Flutter web project and I have a requirement to disable the copy and paste functionality within a TextField widget. I want to prevent users from copying content from this text field and pasting content into it. I've tried a few approaches but haven't been successful yet.

I've already attempted the following approaches:

Setting the `readOnly` property to `true` - This prevents editing the text but doesn't block copy/paste.

Setting the `enableInteractiveSelection` property to `false` - not useful.

Tried with the `toolbarOptions` but seems to be deprecated so i instead used `contextMenuBuilder` as below

```
    TextField(
        contextMenuBuilder: (BuildContext context, EditableTextState editableTextState) {
            return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar.editable(
              anchors: editableTextState.contextMenuAnchors,
              clipboardStatus: ClipboardStatus.notPasteable,
              // to apply the normal behavior when click on copy (copy in clipboard close toolbar)
              // use an empty function `() {}` to hide this option from the toolbar
              onCopy: () => editableTextState
                  .copySelection(SelectionChangedCause.toolbar),
              // to apply the normal behavior when click on cut
              onCut: () => editableTextState
                  .cutSelection(SelectionChangedCause.toolbar),
              onPaste: () {
                // HERE will be called when the paste button is clicked in the toolbar
                // apply your own logic here

                // to apply the normal behavior when click on paste (add in input and close toolbar)
                editableTextState.pasteText(SelectionChangedCause.tap);
              },
              // to apply the normal behavior when click on select all
              onSelectAll: () =>
                  editableTextState.selectAll(SelectionChangedCause.toolbar),
            );
        },
        controller: numericalValueController
    );
```

but still i am not able to prevent user to copy/paste.
Can someone guide me on how to achieve this?

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/a/68185106/4394827 ?

Comment: yes it suggests to use enableInteractiveSelection which i already tried, but not working, also i have tried with the toolbar options but unfortunately it is deprecated.